# Running PHP 5.1.6 on Docker

Tags: php, docker, legacy

Yes the title is correct! A long time a go a website was developed for a student association, the website now has some historical meaning. I'm trying to move the website do a different server, with Docker, but this is a bit harder that I anticipated.

I can't find any repositories with this PHP version. So I tried compiling it from this source: http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.1.6.tar.gz. Then I ran into another problem. All dependencies of this PHP version are old, and I cannot find software repositories with the right versions.

I did found a working php 5.1.6 Dockerfile: https://github.com/nubs/docker-php-minimal/tree/master/php-5.1.6. But here I still have the problem when I add php extensions that have dependencies.

How can I get a working php 5.1.6 installation in Docker?

This is the php configure command of the working installation:

```
./configure
--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
--program-prefix=
--prefix=/usr
--exec-prefix=/usr
--bindir=/usr/bin
--sbindir=/usr/sbin
--sysconfdir=/etc
--datadir=/usr/share
--includedir=/usr/include
--libdir=/usr/lib64
--libexecdir=/usr/libexec
--localstatedir=/var
--sharedstatedir=/usr/com
--mandir=/usr/share/man
--infodir=/usr/share/info
--cache-file=../config.cache
--with-libdir=lib64
--with-config-file-path=/etc
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d
--disable-debug
--with-pic
--disable-rpath
--without-pear
--with-bz2
--with-curl
--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin
--with-freetype-dir=/usr
--with-png-dir=/usr
--enable-gd-native-ttf
--without-gdbm
--with-gettext
--with-gmp
--with-iconv
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr
--with-openssl--with-png--with-pspell
--with-expat-dir=/usr
--with-pcre-regex=/usr
--with-zlib
--with-layout=GNU
--enable-exif
--enable-ftp
--enable-magic-quotes
--enable-sockets
--enable-sysvsem
--enable-sysvshm
--enable-sysvmsg
--enable-track-vars
--enable-trans-sid
--enable-yp
--enable-wddx
--with-kerberos
--enable-ucd-snmp-hack
--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr
--enable-memory-limit
--enable-shmop
--enable-calendar
--enable-dbx
--enable-dio
--with-mime-magic=/usr/share/file/magic.mime
--without-sqlite
--with-libxml-dir=/usr
--with-xml
--with-system-tzdata
--enable-force-cgi-redirect
--enable-pcntl
--with-imap=shared
--with-imap-ssl
--enable-mbstring=shared
--enable-mbstr-enc-trans
--enable-mbregex
--with-ncurses=shared
--with-gd=shared
--enable-bcmath=shared
--enable-dba=shared
--with-db4=/usr
--with-xmlrpc=shared
--with-ldap=shared
--with-ldap-sasl
--with-mysql=shared,/usr
--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config
--enable-dom=shared
--with-dom-xslt=/usr
--with-dom-exslt=/usr
--with-pgsql=shared
--with-snmp=shared,/usr
--enable-soap=shared
--with-xsl=shared,/usr
--enable-xmlreader=shared
--enable-xmlwriter=shared
--enable-fastcgi
--enable-pdo=shared
--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr
--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config
--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr
--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr
--enable-dbase=shared
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with a newer release?  Perhaps not brand new, but something slightly newer?  There is still a [php:5.4-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&page=1&name=5.4-apache) image tagged in the docker library images.

Past that, you may have to build a 5.1.6 image on Linux release that has a similar release time.

Still I hope you have this software in a read-only configuration. A system that old is almost certainly exploitable, and could be attacked and quickly compromised.